# How to optimize this Google Apps Script? All it does is read and write data but it takes forever

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have (what I think is) a simple Google Apps Script that takes parameters from the URL and uses them to write data to a spreadsheet based on whether two of the cells in a row match two of the parameters:

```
function doGet(e) {  
  var email = e.parameter.email;
  var originalTitle = e.parameter.originalTitle;
  var newTitle = e.parameter.newTitle;
  var newAdditionalAuthors = e.parameter.newAdditionalAuthors;
  var newTechnicalSessions = e.parameter.newTechnicalSessions;
  var newApproval = e.parameter.newApproval;

  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById("18vghxzzt27FcBOvoG8kIFFtswMB7XTsMRg60DJ6_-QM").getSheetByName("Responses");
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues(); // read all data in the sheet

  for (n=0;n<data.length;++n){ 
    if (data[n][2] == email && data[n][3] == originalTitle){ //Find all rows where the email matches the submitter's and the title matches the original
      data[n][3] = newTitle;
      data[n][31] = newAdditionalAuthors;
      data[n][33] = newTechnicalSessions;
      data[n][34] = newApproval;
    }; 
    sh.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data); // write back to the sheet
  }

  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success. You may close this tab.");
}
```

However, it seems to take a rather ridiculous amount of time for the script to run, and it just gets worse the more entries I have in the sheet. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you can move sh.getRange(1,1,data.length...).setValues(data) ; outside of the loop.  This is provided the range of data does not include any formulas.  You keep filling the array and writing it to spreadsheet everytime something is added.

Comment: @TheWizEd sweet, thank you so much! It's much faster!